# Does transferring a domain transfers DNS records?

Tags: domain, g-suite, domain-name, domain-registration

Does transferring a domain name automatically transfer all DNS records? I'm transferring to GoDaddy. I'm particularly concerned with the MX records and others which one creates for Google Apps Email and other services.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally, no. It's important to understand that the domain only *references* a nameserver; the DNS records aren't actually stored with the domain registration at all.

When you transfer a domain name, most gaining registrars will leave the nameserver associated with the domain unchanged, so your DNS records will keep working as long as your DNS does. If you are using an external DNS provider, you don't need to do anything else. But if your previous registrar also provided your DNS, now is a good time to manually copy your DNS records somewhere else.

The reason that a registrar can't automatically transfer your DNS records is because most DNS providers have [zone transfers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer) disabled. Without zone transfers, there's no way to know all of the subdomains you might have configured.

Comment: How do I check if I'm using an external DNS provider? Right now I click *Manage DNS* at my current registrar (Solution Point) to change records.

Comment: It sounds like your current registrar is providing your DNS. You can confirm this by querying the nameserver for your domain: `dig mydomain.com ns`.

Comment: Does the same with A record?

Answer (score 1):

No, this will only transfer your NS records.